# Can a sequence have one term?

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry I can't find the answer to this anywhere?

If I have $(7,8]$ can 8 be an accumulation point based upon the assumption that we have the sequence of {$7$} which leads up to 8? but then can I even say that {$7$} has a limit since $$\lim_{x\to\infty} {7} \neq 8$$

I'm a little lost?

Comment: If $(7,8]$ is an interval of the reals, then you have many other points to form a sequence inside it converging to $8$. For example, $a_n=8-1/n$, for $n=2,3,4,...$

Comment: @totoro would the sequence you just suggested be valid since I have to specify $n\ge2$ ? Am I free to create any random sequence so long as it fits?

Comment: You can always write it as $b_n=8-1/(n+1)$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ As long as it is a function from an ordered set with the same 'order shape' as the naturals, you can consider it a sequence, or if you want, build a sequence our of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit of the constant sequence $7$ is $7$, not $8$. But $8$ is a limit point of $(7,8]$ since $8=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(8-\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: On that note, do the terms of the sequence that tends to the accumulation point have to be apart of the domain?

Comment: @K.M. Asserting that $p$ is an accumulation point of a set $A$ means that $p$ is the limit of a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements of $A$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):a_n\neq p$.